# Adding a virtual field to an object

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

```
  def list_links_count do

    query = 
      from l in Link,
        join: c in Click, as: :click,
        where: c.link_id == l.id,
        group_by: l.id,
        select: {l, count(l.id)}

    query |> Repo.all

  end
```

I've got a function that counts that number of clicks per link. The problem is with the final data structure, which is of the form `{Link, 10}`. What I'd really like to do is have it put_in the total, so I can access it more easily in a view, something like `link.click_count`. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the virtual field on your Ecto schema for Link? If not, you'll want to add it:

```
field(:click_count, :integer, virtual: true)
```

Then your select could look something like this:

```
select: %{l | click_count: count(l.id)}
```

Since you now have a `click_count` key in your `Link` structs, you can put that key and still have a list of `Links`. So you should be able to access `link.click_count`.

Comment: This is awesome. I actually can't believe how clean that is. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Kernel.elem/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#elem/2):

```
{Link, 10} |> elem(1) 
#⇒ 10
```

So, within your code:

```
query
|> Repo.all()
|> how_do_you_get_tuple()
|> elem(1)
```